# STM32 usb cdc characters sending-receiving understanding

Tags: serial-port, embedded, usb, cdc

I'm trying to send data from C# app to the one STM32 dev board via USB CDC. I have problem with method SerialPort.Write() because write method send only first character instead of all characters of array or string. Same situation is it with serial terminals (terminte, cutecome,..) when attempt to send string. Can someone explain me how cdc usb really works. Does STM32 send data in same manner, character by character in each frame? I didn't use logic analyzer to see signals but that will be next step maybe.
If anyone has picture of usb cdc frame please share.
When I send string from STM32 dev board to the C# app that works fine. Any idea is welcome

Comment: It sounds as if the problem is on the STM32 side. I recommend you start a new questions focusing on the STM32 code.

Answer (score 0):

The C# SerialPort.Write function is capable of writing an entire string at once if you call it the right way.  The bytes of the string will be passed on to your operating system's USB drivers, which will split it up into packets according to the max packet size for the endpoint specified in your device's USB descriptors.  Then those packets will be sent to the device, one packet at a time.

I suspect that there is a bug in your STM32 code, but since you have not posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it will be difficult to help you debug any code.